# Check if a jquery tools tooltip is already assigned to a component

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools, jquery-tooltip

I have a component to which I assign a tooltip upon first `mouseenter` (sort of a lazy assignment of tooltip to component)

I use the lazy approach since there are many tooltip'able components and I don't want to pre-assign the tooltips to all of them.

```
$(document).delegate(".tooltipable", "mouseenter", function () {
    $(this).tooltip(... options ...);
    $(this).tooltip().show(); // The tooltip will not appear on first `mouseenter` so I have to explicitly show it here
});
```

This works just fine. I would like to improve it so the tooltip will **not** be created on every `mouseenter` by checking if the `tooltip` was already created for this component.

How can that be done?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this.

```
$(document).delegate(".tooltipable", "mouseenter", function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if(!$this.data("tooltipset")){
       $(this).tooltip(... options ...)
       .data("tooltipset", true);
    }
    $(this).tooltip().show(); // The tooltip will not appear on first `mouseenter` so I have to explicitly show it here
});
```

Comment: Thanks, used a similar approach to verify that a tooltip has already been initialised so I can safely destroy it when needed.